# How to set "TAG" when using kotlin-logging in android project?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-logging

I am using [Kotlin-Logging](https://github.com/MicroUtils/kotlin-logging) in my Android App.  How do I set the TAG for my log statements?

Currently in my view-model I have something like:

```
class MyViewModel(private val dictionary: Dictionary) : ViewModel() {
    companion object: NamedKLogging("TAG")
    ....

fun something() {
   logger.i {"something is happening"}
}
```

In Logcat I see:

```
2021-12-13 19:42:51.749 18554-18554/app-name W/System.err: [main] INFO TAG - something is happening
```

What do I need to do to replace the `W/System.err` with `I/TAG`?

Comment: please refer this  https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat

Comment: Thanks @VijayS but I need a way to pass a tag into the log statement.  I read the am-logcat document, i still can't tell how to do that.  If you know how, pls include it in the answer.